# Value Addition for a Key in Python for CSV file output

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Here is my input CSV file.

```
client_ip   listener_service    listener_port
127.0.0.1   LMNO    123
::1         PQAR    768
::1         PQAR    128
12.4.5.2.4          67
```

and Output I want like below

```
client_ip   listener_service    listener_port
127.0.0.1   LMNO                  123
::1         PQAR                 768,128
12.4.5.2.4                         67


 with open('client.csv', 'r') as fin, open('client_out_file.csv', 'w',newline='') as ffout:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        writer = csv.writer(ffout)
        d = {} # Empty Dictionary
        for row in reader:
            nkey = row[0]+row[1] #Creating Key using combinations
            if nkey not in d:
                d[nkey] = row      #Assiging Value to the key
                writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                    #print(row[2])
                    #d[nkey]=d[nkey]+list(row[2])
                    #writer.writerow(row)
```

Need help in **else** part or simpler solution so that if any new value appear for the key it will get included without replacing  previous value . I am trying to avoid saving the csv content in list and then using dictionary - This is taking extra lines. just fyi- I have big csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .As that is like table so tried the screenshot.

Comment: what you wrote in the else part is correct, but you want to avoid creating a list like that???

Comment: When i am doing like that , I am getting lot of repetative rows in my csv and the 'key and 'value' concept of dict does not seems to be convincing. Created Key(combination of two) to filter the identical  .

Comment: can you post what you are getting with the above code???

Comment: if part is like - > if the key is not in dict , create it and assign value(Lets say 1) . Suppose after few iterations we got the same key with with different value , it will go to else part and there the key value should be updated like 1,2 (assuming 2 is the new value seen, 1 for the previous value). The output should  write in the same line as mentioned in output screenshot.

Comment: whats the type of row[2], is it str, or list or int?? also it would be helpful if you can post the csvs....

Comment: str is the type.

Comment: @chrisz Can you please lift your negative input to question , I removed the screenshot and updated as text :) Thank You .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this using the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library:

**`read_csv`**

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv')

    client_ip listener_service  listener_port
0   127.0.0.1             LMNO            123
1         ::1             PQAR            768
2         ::1             PQAR            128
3  12.4.5.2.4                              67
```

**`astype(str)`**

```
df['listener_port'] = df.listener_port.astype(str)
```

**`groupby`** with **`apply`** and **`join`**

```
df = df.groupby(['client_ip', 'listener_service'])['listener_port'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()

    client_ip listener_service listener_port
0  12.4.5.2.4                             67
1   127.0.0.1             LMNO           123
2         ::1             PQAR      768, 128
```

**`to_csv`**

```
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Final output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately , I have to put this code on some user machine and panda is not inbuilt .

Comment: Also, why I am using dict because if I have port no lets say. '80' 10 times for same ip and service it should also filter the duplicate values. Thats why I am mostly focusing on else part.

Comment: I am accepting your solution as answer . I did installed pandas and dependency on the client desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Since row[2] is an str. You simply concat the str to the already existing key.

```
with open('client.csv', 'r') as fin, open('client_out_file.csv', 'w',newline='') as ffout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(ffout)
    d = {} # Empty Dictionary
    for row in reader:
        nkey = row[0]+row[1] #Creating Key using combinations
        if nkey not in d:
            d[nkey] = row      #Assiging Value to the key

        else:
                d[nkey]+=","+row[2]


    for name, values in d.iteritems():
        print values
        writer.writerow(values)
```

EDIT 1: sorry, your issue was repeating the writerow. So even tough we are creating unique keys in dict, we are writing the row to the csv file. move the writerrow to the end of the loop. Use the following piece of code after the for loop to write the dict to the csv file...

Comment: It will work but it will not put the value in the same row without duplicating the key combinations in csv

Comment: So if one key is created and we assign a value to it. Then on the next iteration, when the same key comes in, we are appending values to it. How does it duplicate the key combinations. Keys are only created when a unique key is encountered.

Comment: Thats write, but we are writing that to csv and in csv it do not recognize the duplicate thing. However the key value is changed at run time

Comment: You can try from your end taking the same input example from screenshot.

Comment: Can you please edit your parent code and include the correction there , this way it will be very clear

Comment: Its same things if u are using d.items()